# Android N: dealing with lack of CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-jobscheduler

My `AppWidgetProvider` (which is of course a `BroadcastReceiver`) is registered to receive `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`, so that I can update the widgets as soon as network is restored (though only if required, i.e. if a previous update was missed due to lack of connectivity).

But as set out [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background-optimization.html), this will no longer be possible in Android N.  The suggestion is to use `JobScheduler`, which allows you to specify that the Job should run only when connected to a network by way of the `.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)` method.

However, I can't see how this can be used to replicate my desired behaviour.  It seems to me that the `.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)` method will cause the Job **not to run at all** if there is no network at the time that the Job is scheduled, and it will **not** cause the Job to wait patiently until there is a network and then run (which is what I need).

So, how do I retain the behaviour I need, with Android N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Job Schedulers and it does not depend on whether network is available or not while scheduling the job. It provides certain conditions and when those conditions are satisfied job is scheduled. You can set a repetitive job and also specify minimum time gap between the jobs. For example whenever I connect my phone to charging PlayStore start updating apps as the Job has charging constraint.

If you schedule a job and conditions are not met, it will schedule when network is available. Try to disconnect network and open someone profile on Facebook. It will ask you to load profile on network availability. Now, connect to network and you will get the notification once profile is loaded.

Comment: You can also use firebase dispatcher if you want. It is backward compatible.

Comment: Also you can persist jobs across device reboot.

Answer (score 0):

> try to add google ping for network change that will help you for
>   network change and all cause i have same issue when i was developing
>   with socket services. So may be it will also helps you.